# making a menu in love2d

Tags: menu, love2d

I'm currently working with the love2D game engine and am curious how to create just a simple user menu. Maybe just with a few options such as: Play, options, about, exit.

Are there any good tutorials out there for creating a custom game menu? I just want to get started.

Answer (score 3):

To make a basic menu system, this is what you could do:

- Create a table with the buttons' label, callback, and maybe some other data
- In `love.draw`, loop through that table and draw the buttons
- In `love.update` (also possible in .draw if you want), check if the mouse is hovering over the button
- If the mouse is hovering over the button and has pressed the button, call the button's callback

Now I can't give you all the code needed, because it depends on the rest of your code. However, I can give you a function to check if the mouse is hovering a button:

```
function pointInRectangle(pointx, pointy, rectx, recty, rectwidth, rectheight)
    return pointx > rectx and pointy > recty and pointx < rectx + rectwidth and pointy < recty + rectheight
end
```

And the logic behind checking if the user has pressed the mouse:

- In `love.load`, add `pressed = false`
- In `love.mousereleased`, add `pressed = true`
- At the very end of `love.draw`, just before `end`, add `pressed = false`

Now, if pressed equals true, you know that the user has just released the mouse button.